# How to delete the line breaks in apa-style reference?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I use

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

It is perfect to me, except for one detail: the generated references list is very long.

**Question.**
Is there any way I can remove the line breaks between entries 'Authors', 'Title of article' and 'Journal Title'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` adds a `\par` within each `\newblock` in the bibliography. We can get rid of this be redefining a few bibliography templates:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{white1982,
  author = {White, H.},
  year = {1982},
  title = {Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Misspecific Models},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  volume = {50},
  pages = {1-26}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]